# Why can't I replace a Bone with a Custom Shape (a circle)?

Tags: bones

I want to replace a bone with a custom shape -- a circle.

I add the circle in Object Mode.

I go to Pose Mode & select the bone.  In the Bone Properties tab under Viewport Display/Custom Shape, I select the circle from the "Custom Object" dropdown.  The bone disappears, but the circle doesn't show. Why won't it show?

I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything correctly, because when I follow the exact same procedure to replace the bone with a cube, it works!

Why won't a circle work for this? Is there something special about a circle?

I try checking the Wireframe box, but that doesn't work. All the bones are displayed "In Front" btw.

In fact, I'm following a tutorial & this method works for the instructor in the tutorial... but not for me.  Maybe this is a bug in the latest version of Blender?

Comment: works for me in 3.0b. What version do you have? What OS do you have? Can u provide blend file? From your description - it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had mistakenly added a "curve" circle rather than the "mesh" one. The mesh one works.

Comment: a quirk I've noticed, at least in the 3.x series is that you can use empty objects as bone shapes, but an empty with a circle visualization in particular for some reason results in a bone that is nearly impossible to select. again, other empty visualizations seem to work fine, as well as just using a mesh circle. I figured I'd share after pulling my hair out a bit on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, but I figured it out. I had added a circle from the "curve" menu, rather than the one from the "mesh" menu.  The circle from the mesh menu works.

I'll leave this question up just in case someone else makes the same error. Thanks.